# IE changes onClick with asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, razor

I'm generating a list of radio buttons within my asp.net mvc Application and want to call an javascript method if the radio button is clicked.

This is the Razor Codeline:

```
@Html.RadioButton("selectedArticleMediaAsset", value, new { onClick = "loadData()"})
```

The generated HTML-Line looks like this:

```
<input name="selectedArticleMediaAsset" id="selectedArticleMediaAsset" onclick="loadData()" type="radio" value="../../Content/Images/Bilder_640x640/O20130_XC6_F_Rot_1.jpg|Detailbild 1"/>
```

In Firefox & Chrome everything is running fine, just the Internet Explorer is making problems because the onClick method is generated to onclick with lower case c.
If I change this with the IE-Developer Tool it works.

Any ideas how to generate the correct onClick?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: onclick should work case-insensitively. Have you tried new { onclick = "loadData()" }?

Comment: `onclick` with lower case 'c' is correct, per the [HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#handler-onclick). So please be specific about what "problems" you're seeing. `onclick` should work in IE -- it does for me.

Comment: I started with onclick, it worked fine with Firefox & Chrome.
Now I'm testing in IE and just this time it's not working.
But the curious thing is that if I change the onclick to onClick in the developer Tool it works fine!

Comment: To add some more Information, I don't get any kind of error using Internet Explorer. It's just that if I don't change the 'c' to an upper case 'C' my javascript method isn't even called. I don't see any other problems than the 'c', even if it should be correct this way.

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to solve the problem here. The casing is unlikely to be the issue, but I can't tell from your description what the real issue is. I can say, however, that `onclick` is the *correct* attribute casing, per the standard.

Comment: Okay thanks so far, I hope I'll find the source of this problem soon. I guess this will be my first Christmas miracle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using jquery instead of html attributes?

```
@Html.RadioButton("selectedArticleMediaAsset", value)

<input name="selectedArticleMediaAsset" id="selectedArticleMediaAsset" 
    type="radio" 
    value="../../Content/Images/Bilder_640x640/O20130_XC6_F_Rot_1.jpg|D..."/>

$(function() {
    $('#selectedArticleMediaAsset').click(function() {
        loadData();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good morning,
when I use jQuery it works. But only for the first time I use one of the Radio Buttons displayed on the page.

Comment: It's working now, the problem with jQuery was that only the first radioButton was given the click function.
But if you use jQuery's each function before it works just fine.